# system.web.extension problem

Tags: asp.net-2.0

```
THIS is the error i am getting when i am compiling my project
```

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions,

Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its

dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

```
Source File: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\data\Web-page adversting

impression 2\web.config    Line: 25 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the 

assembly 'System.Web.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the **System.Web.Abstractions** DLL is set to "Copy Local = true" (right click on the properties for the reference).

Comment: can tell me where to double check where to find or add it

Comment: did you read my answer? right click/properties on the DLL (under references for the project which you use it in), make sure it has the setting "Copy Local = true"